# Different Color For different application xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

i created a project named :'Proj1' and i created Proje1.Client1.Android , Proje1.Client2.Android , Proje1.Client1.iOS and Proj1.Client2.iOS
i created a AppConfiguration: in the projet Proj1

```
public class AppConfiguration
   {

       public static class Colors
       {
           public static Color Client1= Color.Black;
           public static Color Client2= Color.White;
       }

       public static class Images
       {
           public static string Client1= "logo1.png";
           public static string Client2= "logo2.png";
       }
}
```

and i created Controls Class :

```
 public class CustomButton : Button
    {
        public CustomButton()
        { BackgroundColor = AppConfig.Colors.Client1;}    
    }
```

and short code from xaml code:

```
<StackLayout><Button:CustomButton /></StackLayout>
```

i want to know if there is a solution for configure color and images for each application (Client1,Client2)

Comment: You can change different color runtime using [Theme in Xamarin.Forms Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/theming/theming)

Comment: great solution.
thank you ,